# Making bootstrap menu visible on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know much about Boostrap and I tried finding the answer online but without success.

I'm building a website for the little company I work for based the the following template:

https://dcrazed.com/bent-app-landing-page-template/

I've customized the texte a little bit of the layouts but my boss wants the menu bar to be always visible. In the template the bar wil appear has you start scrolling down and always be hidden on the home page. I have managed to make it appear and stay on after the first scroll by changing the If conditions of the script.

//MENU APPEAR AND HIDE
$(document).ready(function() {

```
"use strict";

$(window).scroll(function() {

    "use strict";

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $(".navbar").css({
            'margin-top': '0px',
            'opacity': '1'
        })
        $(".navbar-nav>li>a").css({
            'padding-top': '15px'
        });
        $(".navbar-brand img").css({
            'height': '35px'
        });
        $(".navbar-brand img").css({
            'padding-top': '0px'
        });
        $(".navbar-default").css({
            'background-color': 'rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.7)'
        });
    } else {
        $(".navbar").css({
            'margin-top': '0px',
            'opacity': '1'
        })
        $(".navbar-nav>li>a").css({
            'padding-top': '15px'
        });
        $(".navbar-brand img").css({
            'height': '35px'
        });
        $(".navbar-brand img").css({
            'padding-top': '0px'
        });
        $(".navbar-default").css({
            'background-color': 'rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.7)'
        });

    }
});
```

});

Even when changing the conditions of the If it still needs a least one scroll to appear.

Comment: why not just do away with the javascript function altogether? If you want it to display right away and be there all the time than just do so with CSS and eliminate the scroll function

Answer (score 0):

If you add `trigger('scroll')` you should be able to see it immediately.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){  
  // some code
}).trigger('scroll')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 (JS):

If you still want to use js, you could wrap your logic/method into a function like `resizeHandler`, then call it on page load `resizeHandler();`

OR as @a.barbieri said use `.trigger('scroll')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  //scroll handler
  $(window).scroll(resizeHandler);
  //init
  resizeHandler();

  function resizeHandler(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $(".navbar").css({
        'margin-top': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
      })
      $(".navbar-nav>li>a").css({
        'padding-top': '15px'
      });
      $(".navbar-brand img").css({
        'height': '35px'
      });
      $(".navbar-brand img").css({
        'padding-top': '0px'
      });
      $(".navbar-default").css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.7)'
      });
    } else {
      $(".navbar").css({
        'margin-top': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
      })
      $(".navbar-nav>li>a").css({
        'padding-top': '15px'
      });
      $(".navbar-brand img").css({
        'height': '35px'
      });
      $(".navbar-brand img").css({
        'padding-top': '0px'
      });
      $(".navbar-default").css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.7)'
      });
    }
  }

});
```

#### Option 2 (CSS):

use a media query to determine screen size to show and hide.

> ### Using media queries
>
> A media query consists of an optional media type and zero or more expressions that limit the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color. Media queries, added in CSS3, let the presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output devices without having to change the content itself.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @Highfalk Welcome to stackOverflow. If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!